# VBA - Copying a range of cells (Random Row)

Tags: excel, vba, random, range, cells

First time user so I apologise if my question does not follow the format guidelines.

I have several sheets of data that change everyday that I wish to reconcile.
In one particular sheet, a list of customers is detailed with information about them.
As part of the reconciliation I need to choose one of these companies at random and list certain details of them

These details are in columns 3, 5, 7, 14 and 20.

Below I have pasted the code where I work out how many customers there are in a day (last row) and take a random customer and list the data.

However I keep getting a runtime error 450:Wrong number arguements or Invalid property assignments.

Can anyone help me?

```
'Regency
        Dim Regrows As Integer
        Dim RegCust As Integer
        Dim Regcustomer As Range

        AgedDebtors.Activate
        AgedDebtors.Sheets("Regency").Activate
        Regrows = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RegCust = Int((Regrows - 45 + 1) * Rnd + 45)

        With AgedDebtors.Sheets("Regency")
            Regcustomer = Range(Cells(RegCust, 3), Cells(RegCust, 5), _
                                Cells(RegCust, 7), Cells(RegCust, 14), _
                                Cells(RegCust, 20))
            Regcustomer.Activate
        Selection.Copy

        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Set` when assigning a value to an object variable, but your main problem is `Range()` doesn't work the way you want it to here.

```
Set Regcustomer = .Range(Replace("C?,E?,G?,N?,T?", "?", RegCust))
```

You don't need the sheet to be active to copy the range, nor do you need to activate the range

```
    Dim Regrows As Integer
    Dim RegCust As Integer
    Dim Regcustomer As Range

    With AgedDebtors.Sheets("Regency")
        Regrows = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RegCust = Int((Regrows - 45 + 1) * Rnd + 45)
        .Range(Replace("C?,E?,G?,N?,T?","?",RegCust)).Copy
    End With
```

Comment: Clever solution.  I was going to suggest an Intersect version, but I like this way better.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Your help is much appreciated.